# In Javascript, how to refresh parent window from child window without closing the child window?

Tags: javascript

I tried the following Javascript code where I am trying to reload a parent window from a child window without closing the child window.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function refParent () {
   if (window != null) {
       alert('Not null');
       window.opener.reload();
   }
   else {
       alert('null');
   }
}
</script>
```

Then in the HTML code I have the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="refParent();">refresh</a>
```

I do see that the Javascript function is triggered and the window is not null, but the parent page does not appear to refresh.

Is there a way to refresh the parent page without closing the child window?

PS: I would like to be able to do this with a form submission, where the user sees the results of the form submission in the child window, but the parent window gets refreshed. so the event would be on a form submission rather than a click on a hyperlink.

Comment: is impossible, mismatched the html, is a bad approach, ajax calls is the best practice to do this.

Comment: @Sk could you please explain why this is a bad approach?

Comment: because, child and parent is connected,  refresh entire possible server_side, together with html and css, and javascript supose a heavy charge to reload all again whe you needs become in a data change.. ajax supply this functionally without recharge the entire serverside, html, robots, cookies, etc...is like put a small toy in a giant truck an transport them...alone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function refParent(){
  window.opener.location.reload(); 
}
```